# Как фильтровать с django_filters.UUIDFilter

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

У меня есть две модельки

```py
class Work(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    control = models.ForeignKey('work.Control', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```py
class Control(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

И я с помощью django_filter пытаюсь фильтровать по полю *control* чтобы получить все модели **Control** связанные с ней

```py
class WorkFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    control = django_filters.UUIDFilter(field_name='control__id', lookup_expr='iexact', widget=CSVWidget)
```

Но при этом когда я делаю фильтрацию и вставляю **UUID** то django мне выдает `{control:["Enter a valid UUID."]}`

**Пытался делать**

1.Переделывать на фильрацию `django_filters.CharFilter()` но это выдавало ошибку на то что запрос не является UUID

2.Доставать из postgresql сам ID и приводить его к 32-символьной форме (убирал тире)

3.Менять `default=uuid.uuid4` на `default=uuid.uuid1`

Не помогает

Пытался через get_queryset, но у меня с ним проблемы так как только недавно в джанге